# Merge sort, the recursion part

Tags: recursion, merge

After studying the merge sort for a couple of days, I understand it conceptually, but there is one thing that I don't get.

What I get:

1.) It takes a list, for example an array of numbers and splits it in half and sorts the two halfs, and in the end merges them together.

2.) Because it's an recursive algorithm it uses recursion to do that.
    So the split of the mentioned array looks like this:

[image]

It, splits the array until there is only one item in each list and by that its considered sorted. And at that point the merge steps in.
Which should look like this:

[image]

What I don't get is, how does the recursion "know" after it splits all the lists to only one item in a list, to get back up the recursion tree? How does something that has a left and right side become the left side after it merges?

The thing that bothers me is this. I've taken a snapshot of the code from interactivepython page
[image]

How does the code get to the point, after we have lefthalf = 2, and righthalf = 1, to to code that's shown in the picture where the lefthalf = [1,2] and righthalf = [4,3] without going back to the recursion that would divide what we have have merged?

Tnx,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the list only contains one element, each pair of leaves are sorted and joined. Then you can traverse through the list and find out where the next pair should be inserted. The recursion "knows" nothing about going back up the recursion tree, rather it is the act of sorting and joining that has this effect.

Comment: so the traversing through the recursion tree(backwards) is not dependent on the recursion, but on the merging?

Comment: That's correct. Another way to think about it: to go "forwards" you break the list into smaller pieces, so to go "backwards" you have to join them back up.

Comment: but, how merging of two elements for example [3] and [4], when merged into a new list [3,4] doesn't call back the recursion once again?

Comment: It does - there are two levels of recursion, one iterates through the list of pairs, the other iterates until there is nothing else to join. i.e once the single elements are joined into pairs, the pairs then join to form fours etc. until there is only one big list left.

Comment: yeah, that part is really bugging me! I just cant wrap my head around it!

Comment: Perhaps seeing some code will help - notice how the merge function is recursive, and so is the mergesort function that calls on it - https://smthngsmwhr.wordpress.com/2012/11/09/sorting-algorithms-in-haskell/#mergesort

Comment: tnx man, I've reformulated my question a little further, if you have some new ideas please enlighten me:)  Tom

Answer (score 1):

The "recursion" does of course know nothing of that sort. It is the code that uses the recursion, which looks like this (a bit simplified):

```
sort list = merge (sort left_half) (sort right_half)
    where
         (left_half, right_half) = split list
```

Here you see that the "recursion" (i.e. the recursive invocations of `sort`) don't need to "know" anything. Their only job is to deliver a sorted list, array or whatever.

To put it differently: If we have `merge` satisfying the following invariant:

```
1. `merge`, given two sorted lists, will return a sorted list.
```

then we can write mergesort easily like outlined above. What is left to do in sort is to handle the easy cases: empty list, singleton and list with two elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about odd numbered sub lists, then it is dependant on the implementation.

It either puts the bigger sub list on the left every single time, or it puts it on the right every single time.